# What is the correct term of a chemical formula for very large molecules if not just "chemical formula"?

Tags: molecular-structure, proteins, teaching-lab

I know that many molecules, wihch I as a non chemist, might define as "small" if their two dimensional diagram can be sketched on an A4 page, are often `formulated`;
That is → by one or more processes given a [chemical formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_formula);
Maybe after being isolated from a natural deposit or organism.

For example, here is *such* formula for vitaminB<sup>12</sup> of the type [hydroxocobalamin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxocobalamin):

```
C62H89CoN13O15P
```

### My problem

Whenever I examined a wiki article about a protein molecule, I understood it as too big to be represented in a "chemical formula", let alone in a two dimensional diagram on an A4 page, such as those I have described.

I though for example:

> As these are isolated molecules after all, they do have a "chemical formula" and should be **standardly** represented somehow.
>
> Such large molecules doesn't have to be proteins → maybe proteins and other molecules in similar size have different ways to be represented.

### My question

What is the correct term of a chemical formula for very large molecules (such as proteins), if not just "chemical formula"?

From prior research I understand a "protein sequence" is the standard parallel for "chemical formula" in the context of proteins but I don't know about a standard parallel to such large molecules in general.

Comment: Chemical formula is chemical formula, not much to say about it — whether it's one of the largest proteins, [titin $(\ce{C169719H270466N45688O52238S911})$](https://pdb101.rcsb.org/motm/185), [polyoxomolybdate $(\ce{(NH4)12[Mo36(NO)4O108(H2O)16] · 33 H2O})$](https://doi.org/10.1002/zaac.19946200405) or ammonia $(\ce{NH3}).$ I suspect your confusion arises from mixing up *molecular formula* with its abbreviated forms and various graphical representations of *structural formulas*.

Comment: There can't be and isn't such thing in general. There are, however, certain local approaches in the areas which are important to us for some reason or another: protein sequence, DNA sequence, etc.

Comment: What does JohnDoea want to change ? Why is he not satisfied about the word "Chemical formula" ? Chemical formula can be applied to very large molecules. Where is the problem ?

Comment: @Maurice there is no problem and I am totally satisfied with the word - I used my own words then to find the parallel or shortcuts for very large materials where a chemical formula `line` is very long. Anyone is welcome to communally suggest an edit to try to make the question more reachable and shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chemical formulas of the type you describe are just as valid for large molecules as for small ones. The reason they are not commonly used is that the number of possible molecules described by a given formula goes up exponentially with the number of atoms.

Thus, it is much more common to describe larger molecules with more precise terms. In the case of polymers like proteins or nucleic acids, the *primary sequence* of the constituents (amino acids or bases) is often used if space allows. Alternatively, a protein or nucleic acid  might be referred to by a common name with which a sequence is associated.

Even for small molecules, IUPAC formal names or common names are used in preference to molecular formula in many cases, because the names provide information about the atom connectivity that is absent in the molecular formula. Other representations that include connectivity information are forms such as SMILES, which is a standardized system for representing connectivity in text.

In the scientific literature, names of molecules are often accompanied by pictorial representations that provide atom connectivity information in an easily understood format. For very large molecules like proteins whose connectivity cannot be easily represented in a small image, pictorial representations are more often used to show secondary and tertiary structural features.

Comment: Nice answer as the question could attract various and reasonable comments that do not remove the doubt of the asker. This goes to the points.